# Load socket.io with cordova android build

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, sockets, socket.io

I have a small chat app project that I created with node.js, express and socket.io. And installed those modules with npm. App is working on the desktops as expected. I'm trying to built the android version of the app with cordova. And when i run `cordova run android` it opens the app on my phone and load the main ui with no problem and however it really doesn't work (functions) and I get this **error in Chrome developer console remote devices,** when i add socket.io js file like this in index.html

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

> socket.io.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Since app is running on **port 3000 on localhost** then I tried add the socket.io js script like this in the index.html

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

And then this error occurs

> Refused to load the script 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'".

This is the **Content-Security-Policy meta tag**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import the socket.io file from the app storage remove the first slash and ensure that the file are present inside the www folder.

For android check in platforms/android/app/src/main/assets/www the content of that folder is the content of your app. Check there if your socket.io file is present and with the correct path.